# React Media Recorder not recording stream on environment facing camera

Tags: reactjs, mediarecorder

I am having issues implementing React Media Recorder on 'front facing' (environment facing camera).

I have returned the 'status' prop of the react media Recorder as the first line of my functional component to see what is going on. When I deploy the code and test it on mobile device, the 'status' prop of

```
const {
    status,
    startRecording,
    stopRecording,
    mediaBlobUrl,
  } = useReactMediaRecorder({ video: true, audio: true, blobPropertyBag: {
    type: "video/mp4"
} });
```

momentarily changes from 'idle' to 'acquiring-media', and then reverts back to 'idle'. The status never changes to recording and so when I complete the recording, there is no recorded file captured. This is not the case if I use the 'user' facing camera on the mobile, or if I run the user facing or environment facing camera on the desktop device. The functionality works correctly and the 'status' changes from 'idle' to 'acquring_media' to 'recording' to 'stopped' as the user performs video capture and the video is captured just fine.

```
    const RecordNow = () => {

    const {
        status,
        startRecording,
        stopRecording,
        mediaBlobUrl,
      } = useReactMediaRecorder({ video: true, audio: true, blobPropertyBag: {
        type: "video/mp4"
    } });
    
    // Starts recording of new video
         const startedRec = () => {        
         startRecording();
         setIsFilePicked(false)
         setCurStatus(false);  
         let element = document.getElementById('start-record')
      element.parentNode.removeChild(element)
     }

     // Stops recording of new video and creates blob
     const stoppedRec = () => {
       console.log("Recording stopped")
       stopRecording();
       setCurStatus(true);
      setIsFilePicked(true);
  }))
     
}

    const cancelRecord =()=>{
      setCurStatus(true);
      setIsFilePicked(false)
    }
 

   return (
     <div>
       <p>{status}</p>
       {!isFilePicked ?
        <div>
            <Webcam 
              height={size.height} 
              width={size.width}
              videoConstraints={{facingMode: {exact: "environment" },aspectRatio: ratio}}
              ref={camera => window.camera = camera} 
          />
          <button className="close" onClick={back} title="back"><i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i></button> 
          <div>
            <Button id="start-record" onClick={startedRec}>Record</Button>
          </div>
        </div>
         :
       <div>
         <video
        width={size.width}
        height={size.height} 
        controls src={mediaBlobUrl}/>
        <ul className="video-options">
          <li><span><button onClick={uploadToDB} title="upload"><i class="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt"></i></button></span></li>
          <li><span><button onClick={cancelRecord} title="back"><i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i></button></span></li>
        </ul>
        <br />
        <br />
        </div>
       }
       {curStatus ?
      //  <div className="centre"> 
      // </div> 
      <></>
       : 
        <div>   
           <Button id="stop-record"  onClick={stoppedRec}>Stop</Button>
        </div>  
       }
     </div>
   );
 };
```

If anyone has any experience with front facing camera and react-media-recorder I'd appreciate your advice?
I wonder if it might not be possible to record on this camera??

Comment: Hi @Paddyd101 I have been successful in creating a video recorder using the react-media-recorder I do not know what is the particular issue in your case but maybe you will find the solution from my code on github 
[link](https://github.com/bedmuthaapoorv/Simple-Video-recorder-In-React)

Comment: @ApoorvBedmutha. Thanks for your message. This is great and works perfectly with user facing camera. Do you have any idea how I can adapt this to utilse the environment facing camera? I have tried to add `videoConstraints={{facingMode: { exact: "environment" }}}` to line 49 of your App.js file but that doesn't force the necessary functionality.